# new EdgeDriverのタイミングで、Edgeでアプリとしてインストールしたサイトが落ちる

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge

SeleniumによりEdgeを自動制御して操作するアプリを作ったのですが、
new EdgeDriver()をするタイミングで、起動していた**アプリ化したサイト(※)**が閉じられてしまいます。
*※Edgeの「…」メニューから「アプリ」→「このサイトをアプリとしてインストール」を実行しアプリ化したもの。*

起動済みのアプリ化したサイトを閉じずにnew EdgeDriver()する方法は無いのでしょうか？

アプリの情報
・Windowsアプリケーション（Windows Form）
・C#　.NET Framework 4.8
・Selenium.WebDriver 4.16.2
・Selenium.Support 4.16.2

該当処理

```
var driver = new EdgeDriver(driverServiceEdge);
```

driverServiceEdge = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(~~~)でドライバサービスを指定しています。

Comment: この記事 [Microsoft Edge WebDriver を使用して WebView2 アプリを自動化してテストする](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/webdriver) のこちらのセクション [手順 4b: 実行中の WebView2 アプリに Microsoft Edge WebDriver をアタッチする](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/webdriver#step-4b-attaching-microsoft-edge-webdriver-to-a-running-webview2-app) の記述とかが参考になるかもしれませんね。

Comment: ちなみに、そのアプリ化して起動・動作させているサイトをSeleniumで操作したいのでしょうか？ それとも全然関係無いことを行いたいのにSeleniumを使おうとするとアプリが落ちるということなのでしょうか？

Comment: 言葉足らずですみません。アプリ化して起動しているサイトはそのままの状態で、ツール（自作したアプリ）からSeleniumで新規にEdgeブラウザを起動して操作しようとしています。ただ、ツールでnew EdgeDriverをするとアプリ化して起動しているサイトが閉じてしまうため困っています。

Comment: 様々な条件を変えたりして調べてみる必要がありそうですね。まずアプリ化/Selenium双方で詳細なログが取得出来るか試して問題発生時点の状況が分ればそこを重点的に調べられるでしょう。ログ採取が出来ても出来なくても、user-data-dir等のオプションを変えてみるとか、アプリ化を最新版のedgeに更新してやり直すとか、アプリ化とSeleniumで対象ブラウザ(edge/chrome/firefox(はアプリ化可能か?))を変えてみるとか、色々と考えられます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。そうですね。できることをいろいろ試してみます。